# how to add events to calendar after installing CalendarBundle - jQuery fullcalendar bundle?

Tags: events, symfony, calendar

I installed CalendarBundle - jQuery fullcalendar by following the tutorial on this link: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle and I succeeded to display the calendar. But the problem is that I can't add events by clicking on the calendar despite I added an Event Listener class by following this part of the tutorial: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle#adding-events. In addition I don't know how to deal with database using the bundle I installed.

So, what shall I do exactly??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created you database?

Comment: No, I haven't, but how shall I create it??..I mean which tables should I create and for each table which fields should be created?? do you have any idea??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever managed to create the events?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to install this bundle before, the following may work & may not, may even not working with doctrine but it worth testing:
Try to generate a new bundle
 `php app/console generate:bundle`
Then generate entities you need (in the tutorial you posted they say there is Entity/EventEntity class, so 
`php app/console doctrine:generate:entity`
Then create your data base 
`php app/console doctrine:database:create` 
(try to follow entity description in that documentation to know what are the fields that must be inserted)
Now update everything: 
`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
and 
`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: What's the result you get when you render `calendar.html.twig` ?

Comment: well the calendar is displayed, but the problem is that I am not able to add events when I click on the calendar...I am so sorry, I wished to show you some screenshots, but unfortunately I am not able to post images as i don't enough reputation points (I have just 9 points while I need 10 points at least to post images)

Comment: Have you tried to implement the last two part of the tutorial? (Adding Events & Extending the Calendar Javascript)

Comment: well for the part "Adding Events" I did, but for the part "Extending the Calendar Javascript" not yet, in fact, I don't know where should I put the below code exactly:

eventSources: [
        {
            url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
            type: 'POST',
            // A way to add custom filters to your event listeners
            data: {
                filter: 'my_custom_filter_param'
            },
            error: function() {
               //alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
            }
        }
]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You said that you want to `add events when I click on the calendar`, I guess this is done with javascript so that's the part you need to fix, I don't know how to do it exactly but try to do as he said `copy the calendar-settings.js in Resources/public/js` and `custom filters to your event listeners`, this link may help you to understand how to create an event listener [symfony eventlistener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)

Comment: well I think there are no special thinks at the link you gave me, but by the way, I would like to know if it is impossible to integrate wdCalendar calendar in Symfony2. please have a look at this link: [http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php). In fact that is what I would like exactly to have in my project, do you have any idea to do that??..thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this [package](http://plugins.symfony-project.org/get/sfCalendarPPPlugin/sfCalendarPPPlugin-1.0.1.tgz)

Comment: ok...will tell me how to install it and how to use it please?..I am a beginner in Symfony2.